# How do I get the value of a submit button put into a global variable onclick?

Tags: javascript

How do I get the value of a submit button put into a global variable onclick?

```
<input type="submit" value="2">
```

How would I get the value of "2" to say a variable named subVal?

For example, something like this:

```
<script>

var subVal

</script>

<input type="submit" value="2" onclick="subVal = VALUE OF CURRENT SUBMIT THAT WAS CLICKED HERE">
```

Comment: not sure what you mean by "put into a global variable onclick?".
but you can access the value of any element in html by defining its id or by name. code : document.getElementbyId("element ID").

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't provided any context with which to find the `input` element, I'll just provide the most basic way:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].onclick = function (e) {
  window.somevar = e.currentTarget.value;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You may have to add an attribute 'id' to your input tag something like this.

```
<input id="button" type="submit" value="2">
```

and then you can get your value "2" like this,

```
var subVal = document.getElementById("button");
```

Comment: Yea, but I won't know the Id of the submit button clicked. I want to have a variable amount of submit buttons - like 30-100. Each, when clicked, would submit a value to a Javascript function, which would then pull a row <tr>, and get the innerHTML of all the child elements.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you know that global variables are nocive. But here is a way:

```
<script>
  var subVal;
</script>
<input type="submit" value="2" onclick="subVal = this.value" />
```